# Как в Linux открывать VIM с конфигами без sudo?

Tags: linux, vim

Есть vim, всё работает когда захожу при помощи sudo, но когда захожу как обычный юзер запускается стоковый vim, знает кто как настроить ?

Comment: Скопировать настройки из своего пользователя в root

Answer (score 1):

по пути **cd ~ -> .vimrc** - находится конфигурационный файл редактора, в него нужно внести нужные конфиги, можно скопировать из конфигов рута.
Пример конфига
**set expandtab** - Преобразовать табы в пробелы
**set tabstop=2** - Размер таба
**set number** - Отображать номера строк